# Server socket listener does not response to emit

Tags: node.js, react-native, socket.io

I have a react native 0.59 app with nodejs 10.2 as backend. The `socket.io` 2.2.0 running on a server and it is 2.1.1 running on the app client. Here is the socket related code:

Nodejs server:

All socket.io related code is in the index.js file:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {

  console.log("socket.id : ", socket.id);
  socket.on('message', (msg) => {
    console.log("msg received by server socket : ", msg);
  });
  console.log("Socketio server is initialized");

  //disconnect
  socket.on('disconnect', async function() {
      try {
          await SocketList.update({
              active: false
              }, {
                  where: {socket_id: isocket.id}
          });
      } catch(err) {
          console.log("err in false socket id", socket.id);
      }
      console.log('disconnected event');
  });
});
```

A listener for `message` is implemented.

React Native App:

The socket.io client used is 2.1.1. The `socket` is initiated in `App.js` and pass to `Chat` component. In the `Chat` component, connect is made with the socket to the server and emit a `message`:

App.js:

```
//socket.io
const socket = io(GLOBAL.BASE_URL, {
  transports: ['websocket'],
  jsonp: false
});

let props = {
  eventId: "",
  user: ""
};
const ChatWithSocket = (props) => (<Chat {...props} socket={socket} />)

//create the navigator
const navigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Event:  Event,
    Chat: {
      screen: ChatWithSocket,

    } 
  }, {
    initialRouteName: "Event"
  }
);
```

Component Chat.js:

When user enter a chat message and click `send`, The socket fires up the connect and `emit` a `message` with the message entered by the user:

```
   _onSend(messages = []) {
      console.log("socket.io in chat _onSend : ", this.props.socket.id);
      this.props.socket.connect();
      this.props.socket.on('connect', () => {
          socket.emit("message", {msg: messages[0].text});
      });
      this.setState(previousState => ({
        messages: GiftedChat.append(previousState.messages, messages),
      }))
    }
```

The problem is after the chat message is sent from the app, there is no response from the server and the following socket listener code is not executed:

```
socket.on('message', (msg) => {
    console.log("msg received by server socket : ", msg);
  });
```

Here is the console output (portion) on Nodejs server:

```
Listening on port 3000...
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
DB connection has been established successfully.
socket.id :  U0Vm-O5ainh-IRusAAAA
Socketio server is initialized
err in false socket id U0Vm-O5ainh-IRusAAAA
disconnected event
socket.id :  7qo9ncTog0dhPfL6AAAB
Socketio server is initialized
```

The initial socket connection was closed and the socket `7qo9ncTog0dhPfL6AAAB` is initiated again.

Here is the app console output showing 2 messages have been sent by client `7qo9ncTog0dhPfL6AAAB` which matches the socket.id on the server:

```
4-14 22:21:19.034 26574 26634 I ReactNativeJS: 'socket.io in chat _onSend : ', '7qo9ncTog0dhPfL6AAAB'
04-14 22:21:24.286 26574 26634 I ReactNativeJS: 'socket.io in chat _onSend : ', '7qo9ncTog0dhPfL6AAAB'
```

Comment: Which version of socket.io npm used??

Comment: `this.props.socket.emit("message", {msg: messages[0].text});`. this is the working code. `this.props.socket.on("connect"..)` is removed as it causes the socket client reconnecting each time with reloading. Also I missed the `props` in front of `.socket`.